# RTE ribbon paste button is disabled except on Internet Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-server, ribbon, rich-text, chrome, ie

My customer is complaining that SharePoint's built-in Rich Text Editor's paste button is disabled and copying/pasting only works via keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V.

This happens on Chrome, Firefox and Edge browsers. However, on Internet Explorer the paste button works correctly.

I am quite sure that this is a known issue, and there is nothing that could be done to fix it (please correct me if I am wrong).

However, I have tried to search the internet for a definitive article explaining the problem. I could then show/quote this article to my customer, and have her then accept the current situation.

**My question is**:

Do you have any good pointers to articles/web sites that would explain the reason(s) for this problem:

Why the paste button works in IE, and why is it disabled in other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Some functions are only available in IE. The best way to do it right now is
copying/pasting via keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V.

Some functionality in SharePoint Server requires ActiveX controls. This produces limitations on browsers which do not support ActiveX. Currently only 32-bit versions of Internet Explorer support this functionality.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/browser-support-planning-0

Your browser doesn’t allow clipboard access [FAST FIX] for your reference:

https://windowsreport.com/browser-doesnt-allow-clipboard-access/